# How to do in-place vectorization in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization, in-place

How can I apply a vectorized operation to a pandas.DataFrame or a pandas.Series **in place**? I have only found approaches that create and return a copy.

I'm primarily concerned with reducing resource use, but it would be nice to know if it's possible at all even if it's not especially efficient.

As it stands, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
#  df
#    a  b
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6

df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']
#  df
#    a  b  c
# 0  1  4  5
# 1  2  5  7
# 2  3  6  9

# Or like this
df['c'] = np.log(df['a'])
#  df
#    a  b         c
# 0  1  4  0.000000
# 1  2  5  0.693147
# 2  3  6  1.098612

# Or these methods:
# df['c'] = df['a'].apply(np.log)
# df['c'] = np.vectorize(np.log)(df['a'])
```

But, I would like to do something in place sort of like `data.table` in R is capable of.

```
df[c = np.log(a)]
#  df
#    a  b         c
# 0  1  4  0.000000
# 1  2  5  0.693147
# 2  3  6  1.098612

# or even
df['a'].apply(np.log, inplace=True) # which doesn't exist
# so that column 'a' were transformed in place
# df[['a','b']]
#           a  b
# 0  0.000000  4
# 1  0.693147  5
# 2  1.098612  6
```

Comment: Other than being invalid python syntax, what is `df[c = np.log(a)]` supposed to be doing that's different?  `python/numpy` proivides operators like `+=` that do a kind of iin-place operation (though they still create an intermediate buffer).   Don't try too hard to import foreign language notions.  Learn good python/numpy/pa das first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this...
This still creates an intermediat buffer, but the final dataframe would be the same.

```py
df['a'] = df['a'] + df['b'] # Does not create new column df['c']

df['a'] = np.log(df['a'])
```